# Octave clc does not clean the command window

Tags: octave

In matlab, clc will totally clean the command window. You can't traverse the history using scroll bar. In Octave, it does clean but the history still can be accessed using scroll bar. This is pretty annoying when debugging.

This behavior is observed with Octave 6.2.0 on Ubuntu 20.04, installed via snap.

Comment: This seems like a bug report, which you should instead do on the Octave bug tracker: https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/bugs — If you have an actual question, please be specific, I don’t see how anyone could post a useful answer to your question.

Comment: I thought if someone has a solution since I may miss something in the Preference. I will submit the bug report instead.

Comment: here is the link to the bug report: https://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/index.php?61000

Comment: Octave, like many other terminal-based programs (e.g. python, julia), uses the readline library. The behaviour you describe is not a 'bug', it's just how readline behaves. In fact, matlab behaves the same way in the terminal (i.e. if run with the -nodesktop flag).

Comment: Well, that's good to know the readline library is used. However, Octave is  supposed to be a Matlab replacement, should it not behave the same?

Comment: @kstn This is a common misconception. Octave is not "supposed to be a matlab replacement", especially in the UI sense. They are similar projects, with similar goals, sharing a common language subset, but they also have important differences. In some ways matlab is 'better', and in others octave is 'better', depending on your needs. __Because__ of the similarities they share, and to please their user-base, octave devs go to great lengths to ensure compatibility with matlab when possible. Similarly, matlab has borrowed several language features that were first introduced and tested in octave.

Comment: (though it can be argued that matlab occasionally goes to some lengths to try and break this compatibility with octave, due to the competitive position in which their business model forces them into ... but apparently this is a slightly controversial statement :p ). In any case, matlab compatibility, where present, is a "feature" of Octave, not a "raison d' etre". And where so, the focus is on matlab-the-language. Copying the look and feel of Matlab-the-product / matlab-the-interface is not one of the project's goals. In fact octave didnt really even have an official gui until fairly recently.

Comment: @TasosPapastylianou well, of course Octave and Matlab are two different projects. But the way Octave is advertised make user feel it can be a Matlab alternative and it actually does a fairly good job in that. I do not want to argue in that particular aspect, rather than the behavior of clc command itself. Right now I think it is not good enough and if it's improved will improve user experience.

Comment: @kstn Fair enough. But, in fairness, I wouldn't expect much to come out of such a bug report, for a couple of reasons: a) I'm not convinced that 'resetting' rather than 'clearing' the terminal is preferable; personally I prefer the latter (particularly for debugging purposes, since I get the benefit of a clean screen without losing earlier output!). 2. Since readline is such a core dependency, unless there's a simple fix I'm ignoring which could be a simple tickbox, it is highly unlikely the devs will want to get rid of it for such a simple/subjective issue, just for the sake of 'matlabness'.

Comment: Btw, ironically, what you're asking is possible when running octave in a standard terminal (i.e. not the gui version of octave), by doing `fprintf('\033c')` (see: https://askubuntu.com/a/684887/622983 ). I think if you rephrase your bug report more as "why does fprintf("\033c") clear instead of reset the terminal in the octave gui?", you might attract more interest, simply from the sheer 'geek problem' factor :p